# Append strings if not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the view of a rail's app, I want to achieve:

- If user's height isn't `nil`: return the height value with string "cm"
- Otherwise: return string `"N/A"`.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this. The code below:

```
user.try(:profile_name).try(:push("as Alias")) || "N/A"
```

isn't working. The part `try(:push("cm"))` gives me an error. I thought of using the `<<` operator to append strings by using , but I think there should be a neater way to complete this. Is there anyone who can give me a hint?

--another similar example which I want to accomplish but not working:

```
user.try(:height).try(:to_s).try(:push("cm")) || "N/A"
```

Comment: how you decide that `try(:push("as Alias"))` should do what you need? maybe `try(:push, "as Alias")`?)

Comment: Changing example code like that is not very friendly towards existing comments and answers (they now look out-of-place).

Comment: Documentation for the `try` method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: thanks for your advice, I changed it because I noticed an error in my example ( because "profile_name" in the original example should be already in string and it has no sense of putting the successive method .try(:to_s) and I wanted to change it to some other example that is more meaningful, and at that moment I didn't expect that there were already 2 comments ( 1 answer and 1 comment )... Should I revert it to the original, without .try(:to_s)?

Comment: @Mumi: yes, bring back the original example and omit the `to_s`. Also you have the answer in the first comment. Except that String doesn't have `push` method. But it has (at least) a couple of other methods which will do what you intend.

Comment: @IS04, I decided like that, because if neither user nor profile_name are nil (please ignore the part .try(:to_s)), then it could execute the successive method -> :push("as Alias")... I thought up of this by seeing some examples how try() was used together with .to_s, so I thought it might work... But it didn't. And your suggestion doesn't work either... Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev alright, I brought back the original. And thanks to your hint, I found another string concatenation method .concat which works in try() as I expected. The code is:

<code>
#{user.try(:profile_name).try(:concat, "as Alias") || "N/A"}
<code>

Thus, when user variable got nullified in other part: output "N/A"
When user exists but :profile_name's value is nil: output "N/A"
When both user and :profile_name's value exist: output user's profile name with "as Alias" attached... I think I got what I wanted with this code, but any smarter suggestions are still welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
(user && user.profile.present?) ? "#{user.profile} as Alias" : 'N/A'
```

Comment: Hmmmm, your code still gave me an error when evaluting object was nil. I modified your code a bit and changed to:

`code` user.try(:profile_name).present? ? "#{user.profile_name} as Alias" : 'N/A' `code`

and it works as I wanted to. Though, still, repeating the part "user.profile" twice isn't much concise and I think there should be another handy way... Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I assumed user is never nil. Yous hould quit using try too much, there are better ways to do this without try. I'll update answer in a  second